# Build connection between flame and flutter

Tags: flame

I have a flutter widget `ProgressBar`, which needs to be notified when a change happens to a value in Flame,

I followed a tutorial which is using `overlays.notifyListeners();` to update the `StatelessWidget` progressBar, but after I updated to the newest Flame version (`v1.6.0`), this method can not be used anymore, what is the correct way of doing this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, either you can use state management  libraries like `flame_riverpod` or `flame_bloc` to achieve this, or you can wrap your value in a `ChangeNotifier`/`ValueNotifier` and update the state once the value updates.

Comment: Here you can see an example of such a use-case from #17DaysOfFlutter:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=21e84542c90af9d32fa0d37c141e8fec

Comment: Hi Spydon, thanks for the hints as always:) I will check it out

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, we are trying to keep all questions as "answered" on the Flame tag. :)